# Find all if else and else if statements with no parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a bunch of code in c# that has here and there lines where an if or else statement without parentheses got some extra lines which result in false behavior. I am looking for a regex to find all possible places where this problem could occur so i can manually look for it.

To clarify what i mean. In code are a few places (i found until now) where the following code is wrong.

```
if (notInitialized)
    Initialize();
    AdditionalInitializationNotUseThisWhenAlreadyInitialized();
```

which should be

```
if (notInitialized) {
    Initialize();
    AdditionalInitializationNotUseThisWhenAlreadyInitialized();
}
```

I tried this `if\s*\(.*\)([\n\r\s[^{]]*.*);*` but it gives me not only the results i want. It has the `if (notInitialized) {` parts too. I have almost no experience in using regex.

How can i find all these cases without checking every if/else/else if in the code, just the ones without curly braces?

Comment: What is the Regex engine which is going to be used?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Roslyn analyzer. A quick google found some examples that do this.

Comment: Try [`(if\s*\([^()]*\)\p{Zs}*)((?:\r?\n\p{Zs}+\p{L}.*)+)` > `$1{$2\r\n}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=\(if%5cs*%5c\(%5b%5e\(\)%5d*%5c\)%5cp%7bZs%7d*\)\(\(%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%5cp%7bZs%7d%2b%5cp%7bL%7d.*\)%2b\)&i=if+\(notInitialized\)%0d%0a++++Initialize\(\)%3b%0d%0a++++AdditionalInitializationUseThisWhenAlreadyInitialized\(\)%3b%0d%0a%0d%0aif+\(notInitialized\)+%7b%0d%0a++++Initialize\(\)%3b%0d%0a++++AdditionalInitializationUseThisWhenAlreadyInitialized\(\)%3b%0d%0a%7d&r=%241%7b%242%0d%0a%7d)

Comment: Just a quick check, you do know that `if` is allowed without curly braces, and that the expected behavior is to run only the first following line. (so yes as you pointed out running 2 lines only the first is ran when not initialized, maybe move the `AdditionalInit()` into the end of `Initialize()` for cleanness. or move `Initialize()` to the top of `AdditionalInit()`

Comment: Saving this post as an example as to why you should always use braces.

Comment: I am using the search integrated in Visual Studio 2012. It's not needed to do this fully automated or code something around it. Just to check if the old code has some basic bugs into it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That does not work. I get no results.

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian It is not code written by me, i took over the project and found some of this nasty bugs by accident and fixewd them. But i want to ensure that there are not more of them anywhere.

Comment: @TEK It is a feature i never use just like omitting semicolons in JavaScript. But it is used there so i must make the best out of it for now.

Comment: @Booser AFAIK VS 2012 and newer actually use the .NET regex engine, so my regex should work fine.

Comment: rule of thumb, if it works leave it. but as a fix google?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438150/i-want-to-find-all-if-statements-in-c-sharp-code-which-are-not-followed-by-brack

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian I tried a few search queries but i think mine where too complicated... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you are facing is that the regex is matching as much as it can on the `.*` to find a pattern match. Therefore, and depending on the options used (e.g. `.` matches anything but \n, or anything), you'll get unsatisfactory results.

Another problem is that you'd need to match recursively, e.g. skip as many `)` as there were nested '(' in the expression. Only a very few regex engines can do this; .NET fortunately can via "balancing groups" but it is tricky and highly advanced application of regex. Also, for that to work correctly, you'd have to also recognize string and character literals (in quotes) as to not count parens in these.

**Edit** This regex for .NET should pretty reliably find these if and else statements:

```
\b(if\s*\(((?:[^()"']|'(\\.|[^'\\])'|"(\\.|[^"\\])"|(?<parens>\()|(?<-parens>\)))*(?(parens)(?!))\))|else)\s*[^{\s]
```

While this shows how powerful regexes can be, it's very cryptic and the proper way to do this would really be with a real parser (such as Roslyn).

Comment: Dont get me wrong, you know regex really well (better then me probably). But i dont get how one would need such a huge regex for something this simple.

Comment: @MarioDekena Because it covers the corner cases: it should handle anything like curly and non-curly braces in string or character literals, even   lambda expressions in the predicate such as `if (x.Any(y => { return z(); }))` etc.

Comment: This works like i need it. It looks like voodoo (like any regex ;)) But i dig into it to see how it is done. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Booser! Note that if you want to allow the `} else if (x) {` construct, you can replace the `else` in the pattern with `else(?!\s+if\b)` to skip over these. Also I wonder why my post got downvoted...

Comment: I saw some corner cases where it found sometimes some { or left out if statements which should have matched. But it did what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if \(.+?\)[^{]*?\n[^{]*?[^{]
```

If you dont have ifs in a format like this

```
if (notInitialized) 
{
    Initialize();
    AdditionalInitializationNotUseThisWhenAlreadyInitialized();
}
```

this also works:

```
if \(.+?\)[^{]*?\n
```

It will detect, if a line with "if" has no { at the end. Its is also a little shorter.

Comment: @Lucero Your example works. This one liner has no { at the end. It would also work with "{" as the string. And even for the two lined version.

Comment: @Lucero also works... Read my regex! it has a line break at the end. Before that it ensures there is no { after the last ).

Comment: Most of the files are formatted to have the opening { in a new line. Some older ones have them in line.

Comment: @Booser Yes, i am aware of that. Most people have a preference how they want their ifs. Thus the IDE is configured to format them this way. Since in his example he uses the inlined format, its reasonable to assume his IDE might format them like this.

Comment: I hoped you'd get the idea... The regex cannot work reliably for all cases. `if (DoesItFail) a="{";` will be seen as "valid" even though it isn't, and `if (DoesItFail) { b(); };` as invalid even though it is valid.

Comment: @Booser ha! Just realized that was your question! :D See my edit.

Comment: @Lucero Hmm didnt thought of that.

Comment: @MarioDekena The big problem is when there is no guideline how to format and over many years there were so many developers who had all their own style... Most of the code is a mixture of different formattings over hundreds of files. So i leave it until i have changes to do somewhere.

Comment: @Booser Most IDE's can format your entire project according to a specific code style. In our company we work together on a large project. But every IDE is configured the same way, so the code looks the same  everywhere. If we integrate other code, we reformat it first to fit the guidelines.